# Why do the projective objects in a ribbon category form an ideal?

Tags: monoidal-categories

Numerous papers from at least 2001 onward assert without proof that the projective objects in a ribbon category (usually required to be K-linear for K an algebraically closed field, perhaps required to satisfy one or more of abelianness, additivity, or karoubian-ness) form an ideal in the sense that they are closed under retracts and under monoidal product with arbitary objects.

Which added hypotheses are needed, and where can one find a proof of this result in the literature?